# Unexpected token | Parse PHP array to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

When I am parsing a PHP array which is filled with data from a database to JavaScript, I get an error called  `unexpected token '<'` . The code which selectes data from my database is:

```
$wagennummern = NULL;

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `Wagenbuch`");
while($row = $result->fetch()){
    $wagennummern = $row['Wagennummer'];
}
```

The code to use this data in JavaScript is:

```
var wagennummer = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $wagennummern) . '"]' ?>;
```

The Javascript is the line where the error occurs. Can anybody tell me why there is an error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The particular error message could be caused by a combination of characters that includes a `<` in the data.

If you want to convert a PHP data structure to a JS data structure, the `json_encode`, which is compatible with JS. Don't roll your own. Any special character is likely to break your attempt.

```
var wagennummer = json_encode( $wagennummern );
```

---

It might also be caused by the PHP not being executed at all. This would happen if you weren't loading it from a web server, or if you put it in a file with a `.js` file extension instead of a `.php` file.

Comment: hmm doesnt you need to parse it too? like `JSON.parse(json_encode( $wagennummern )))`

Comment: @Ifaruki — No. As I said, `json_encode` is compatible with JS. The generated JSON/JS is not being wrapped in quotes to make it a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Quentin's answer:

I would point out that if your query does not return any row, the variable `$wagennummern` will be `null` (first line of your code)

Trying to feed a null value into `implode` will generate an error, which will be display as HTML, thus creating the `unexpected token '<'` error.

I would suggest to initialize the `$wagennummern` variable to an empty array, that way it will not cause any problems if you have no rows.
Another solution would be to check for the variable being `!== null`

Comment: What would you suggest to initialize ``$wagennummer`` with

Comment: An empty array, this would allow you to have consistent logic. So it would be `$wagennummer = []`.